Satmar Tefillin
I was in a Satmar Shul and was intrigued on the way they wrap Tefilin. Can anybody explain to me how the Satmar Chassidim wrap tefilin Shel Yad, specifically, their wrapping of the hand? Thank you.

Chassidim usually follow the sefardi custom of wrapping.

Looks like satmar follows the standard Ashkenazi wrap on the hand

The Nitei Gavriel on hilchos Teffilin has a bunch of pictures in the back of the sefer depicting many different shittos/minhagim of wrapping.
Satmer wrapping of the hand :

